# Find the maximum integer value $n$ such that $2^n\mid 3^{1024} -1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Since $2^{10} = 1024$ then we can $3^{1024}-1 = ( 3 - 1 )\Pi_{i=0}^{9} {3^{2^i}+1}$

And then we can start eliminating the $3-1=2$ and $(3^2-1)= 2\times 5$

But then? I guess I could calculate, but this is not different as starting calculating in first place.

What is a better method?

Comment: Repeated Difference of Squares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

For $i \geq 1$ you have:
$$3^{2^i}+1 \equiv (-1)^{2^i}+1 \equiv 1+1 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$$

Comment: Note the question is asking about $3^{1024} - 1$, not $3^{1024} + 1$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan yes, and as the OP posted $$3^{1024}-1 = ( 3 - 1 )\Pi_{i=0}^{9} (3^{2^i}+1)$$

Comment: Sorry for not noticing that. I appreciate you explaining it to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint $1$:**

Note that $1024=2^{10}$
$$3^{2^{10}}-1=(2+1)^{2^{10}}-1=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{10}-1}\dbinom{2^{10}}{k}$$

**Hint $2$:**

$3^{1024}-1$ is the difference of squares. Consider the factors to get the answer.

Comment: I consider the factors but, I didnt know how to proceed when I have $(3-1)(3+1)(3^2 +1)...(3^{512}+1)$

Comment: Also you have a litte error in the powers

Comment: @MariaGuthier You can write $3^{1024}-1$ as $(3^{512}+1)(3^{512}-1)$ and $3^{512}-1$ as $(3^{256}+1)(3^{256}-1)$ and so on.... and you will get the final answer as $12$

Answer (score 1):

In general, the order of $3$ mod $2^n$ is $2^{n-2}$ for $n\ge3$ (*). Therefore, the value you seek is $12$.

(*) This follows from $3^{2^{n-3}} \equiv 2^{n-1}+1 \bmod 2^n$, which can be proved by induction.